# Changing attributes of cloned elements using CSS selectors

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to clone an element, and then traverse through it's child elements and change attributes accordingly, the thing is that I am trying to access the elements via custom attributes using CSS selectors and I can't seem to get it to work, here is what I have thus far,

HTML:

```
<div id='main_container'>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div><label>... </label></div>
            <div><input type="text" id="one" new="one_1" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div><label>... </label></div>
            <div>
                <select id="two" new="two_1" >
                    <option>...</option>
                    <option>...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div><label>... </label></div>
            <div>
                <select id="three" new="three_1" >
                    <option>...</option>
                    <option>...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="button" value="add a section" id="button" />
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var clone = $('#container').clone().appendTo('#main_container');

        clone.children('["new*=one"]').attr('class', 'one');
        clone.children('["new*=two"]').attr('class', 'two');
        clone.children('["new*=three"]').attr('class', 'three');
    });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only gets *immediate* or *direct* children, you're looking for [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) here, like this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var clone = $('#container').clone().appendTo('#main_container');

    clone.find('[new*="one"]').attr('class', 'one');
    clone.find('[new*="two"]').attr('class', 'two');
    clone.find('[new*="three"]').attr('class', 'three');
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/3BBdx/1/).

Note the moved quotes above as well.  [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) searches *any* level deep, so all descendants when matching the selector, that's the important difference in this case.  Also, to be safe on the attribute though, I'd use `data-new` instead, it'll be HTML5 compliant as well.

Another thing to keep in mind is with the code you posted, you're getting duplicate IDs, make sure to remove or change those when cloning.

Comment: Thanx, that did the trick! Appreciate you taking the time to explain it, I learnt quite a bit from your post!