# Modifying display size of image on jQuery clone()

Tags: jquery

I'm copying an object (image) into another element. How do I change the size at which it will be displayed in the destination element on the fly?

```
<div id="eleWithImgs">
    <img id="ph01" src=".../image01.jpg">
    <img id="ph02" src=".../image02.jpg">
    ...


$('#eleWithImgs').children().each(function() {

    $($(this), {
        width:  // ??
        height: // ??
    }).clone().appendTo('#destinationEle');

});
```

Comment: clone it **and then** set CSS properties for the cloned element

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing attributes of cloned elements using CSS selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700420/changing-attributes-of-cloned-elements-using-css-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

Set CSS properties for cloned element:

```
$('#eleWithImgs').children().each(function () {
    $(this).clone().css({
        width: // ??
        height: // ??
    }).appendTo('#destinationEle');
});
```

I hope your question was not how to fill the `??` ...

Comment: that was just to illustrate the objective. I was looking for what you have here: `$(this).clone().css({...}).appendTo...`  Thank you

Comment: I don't know why @adeneo has removed is answer, it was far better. I mean, not cloning element (to take care of duplicate IDs)

Comment: ... yes I was responding to it actually... his was the direct way, both work for me

Comment: @adeneo the answer you had here earlier was really helpful, would appreciate having it back for reference for future generations...

Comment: @user3024007 this was his answer, passed it in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2vPcJ/